# Contradiction when using inequality sign as a relation between functions.

Tags: functions, relations

When can we use the equality and the inequality symbol as a relation between functions ?

Consider $f(x)=4$ and $g(x)=1$, then we can easily say $f(x)>g(x)$.

Let $F(x)=2x$ and $G(x)=x$  where both $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ have the domain
  $[1, \infty)$ then $F(x) > G(x)$.

If I change the domain of $F(x)$ to $[1,10]$ and $G(x)$ to $[21,\infty)$ then I can say $G(x) > F(x)$. I can replace the functions and write $x>2x$. But this implies $1>2$ which is not true.  An easy way of solving this can be to let $G(x)=y$, where $x=y$. But this looks like we are cheating.

So in order to use the inequality sign or even the equality sign in some cases as a relation between two functions, do we need both functions to have the same domain?

Besides that, all the output obtained from $G(x)$ will be greater than what we will get from $F(x)$ and hence is writing $G(x) > F(x)$ valid?

Comment: Usually its implies that both $f$ and $g$ will be defined on the same domain.

Comment: @Good Morning Captain So it is a neccessary condition.

Comment: Well you are abusing the letter *x*, that's for sure! If $F: A \rightarrow B$ and $G: C \rightarrow D$, then you can say that $F(A) > G(C)$ or $F(A) < G(C)$, depending on how you define the functions and their domains. Because those are SETS, and the notation implies that every element in one set is larger than every element in the other set, IIRC

Comment: Surely the definition of "one function is greater than another" requires them to have the same domain, and it includes something like "for all x in X, f(x) > g(x)." You are using something more like "for all x in A and for all y in C, f(x) > g(y)"

Comment: @The Chaz 2.0 But if f(x) > g(y) implies 21 > 10, then it should be true. I don't want to sound stupid though.

Comment: Then let's be *precise*! "f(x) > g(y)" is meaningless without more context. You have to define f and g (which will, in the process, tell us from what sets we take x and y). Then you pick specific values from their respective domains and compare their function values. What you call an implication is surely just "f(x) = 21 > 10 = g(y)." ..........finally, what "should be true"?

Comment: @The Chaz 2.0  Ranging from 0 to 100, where 0 represents the question that toddlers ask and 100 the questions The Chaz 2.0 asks, where does my question fit in ? 

Comment: Let's talk in chat! https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection of functions F = { f:(X,<=) -> (Y,<=') }
from an ordered domain into an ordered codomain is
ordered by f <= g when for all x in X, f(x) <= g(x).
Such functions are called order preserving.

Of course this order is not linear, nor do
the orders of X and Y need be linear.

Thusly f < g when f <= g and exists x with f(x) < g(y).
One may like to use
f << g when for all x in X, f(x) < g(x).